# How to import/incorporate a basic python script in Flask without calling it in a route?

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

Using Flask I understand how you can have different python functions doing various things according to the URL you put in.

However- I want to know how/if it's possible to incorporate a python script residing in a different folder into a flask framework?

Take this very basic flask app below...

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('echo.html')

@app.route("/test_one")
def test():
    return("Hello world")
```

For example, how can I 'call' on a separate python script from a folder in the flask framework which prints some text- but which isn't just a basic function connected to one of the routes?

The idea is to apply this concept but to a much more complicated python script which performs a BLAST search.

Answer (score 1):

You can import it as module. Let's say you have another file, functions.py located in the same folder. That file contains many functions, including `printdummy()`, which simply prints the `Hello world!` statement.
Your new code should look like:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from functions import printdummy
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('echo.html')

@app.route("/test_one")
def test():
    return(printdummy())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I followed your instructions but when I try and run it through Pycharm I get the error message:
"   print_dummy():
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

It's the only function I have in the 'functions' file and it's written like 

print_dummy():
return "Hello world!"

Comment: Hi! Just wanted to know that it worked for me. @FrodoBaggings I'm guessing you lack ```def``` at the beginning of your function definition? It should be ```def print_dummy(): ...```

Answer (score 1):

To incorporate a python script residing in a different folder into a flask framework, example

> /PATH_TO_FLASK/hello.py

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import sys
#You need to add the directory that contains script to PYTHONPATH
#There are other ways
#Modify this
sys.path.append('/OTHER_PATH/')
from blast import use_blast

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    xml = use_blast()
    return Response(xml, mimetype='text/xml')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

> /OTHER_PATH/blast.py (Note: biopython required)

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW

seq="""AAAGGTTACCCCCACCGACTTTCGGGTGTTACAAACTCTTCGTGGTGTGACNGGGC
GGTGTGTACAAGGCCCCGGGAAACGTANTTCANCCGCGGCATGCTGATCCGCGAT
TACTAGCGATTCCAGCTTCATGTAGGCGAGTTGCAGCCTACAATCCGAACTGAGAA
CGGTTTTATGAGATTAGCTCCACCTCGCGGTCTTGCAGCTCTTTGTACCGTCCATT
GTAGCACGTGTGTAGCCCAGGTCATAAGGGGCATGATGATTTGACGTCATCCCCA
CCTTCCTCCGGTTTGTCACCGGCAGTCACCTTAGAGTGCCCAACTGAATGATGGCA
ACTAAGATCAAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCAACATCTCACGACACGA
GCTGACGACAACCATGCACCACCTGTCACTCTGCTCCCGAAGGAGAAGCCCTATCT
CTAGGGTTGTCAGAGGATGTCAAGACCTGGTAAGGTTCTTCGCGTTGCTTCGAATT"""

def use_blast():
    result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", seq, hitlist_size=1)
    xml = result_handle.read()
    return xml
```

Run it

```
python hello.py
```

you get,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE BlastOutput PUBLIC "-//NCBI//NCBI BlastOutput/EN" "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/dtd/NCBI_BlastOutput.dtd">
<BlastOutput>
  <BlastOutput_program>blastn</BlastOutput_program>
  <BlastOutput_version>BLASTN 2.6.1+</BlastOutput_version>
  <BlastOutput_reference>Stephen F. Altschul, Thomas L. Madden, Alejandro A. Sch&amp;auml;ffer, Jinghui Zhang, Zheng Zhang, Webb Miller, and David J. Lipman (1997), &quot;Gapped BLAST and PSI-BLAST: a new generation of protein database search programs&quot;, Nucleic Acids Res. 25:3389-3402.</BlastOutput_reference>
  <BlastOutput_db>nt</BlastOutput_db>
  <BlastOutput_query-ID>Query_13451</BlastOutput_query-ID>
  <BlastOutput_query-def>No definition line</BlastOutput_query-def>
  <BlastOutput_query-len>502</BlastOutput_query-len>
  <BlastOutput_param>
    <Parameters>
      <Parameters_expect>10</Parameters_expect>
      <Parameters_sc-match>2</Parameters_sc-match>
      <Parameters_sc-mismatch>-3</Parameters_sc-mismatch>
      <Parameters_gap-open>5</Parameters_gap-open>
      <Parameters_gap-extend>2</Parameters_gap-extend>
      <Parameters_filter>L;m;</Parameters_filter>
    </Parameters>
  </BlastOutput_param>
<BlastOutput_iterations>
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_iter-num>1</Iteration_iter-num>
  <Iteration_query-ID>Query_13451</Iteration_query-ID>
  <Iteration_query-def>No definition line</Iteration_query-def>
  <Iteration_query-len>502</Iteration_query-len>
<Iteration_hits>
<Hit>
  <Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
  <Hit_id>gi|725611268|gb|KM660696.1|</Hit_id>
  <Hit_def>Bacillus cereus strain MGH118 16S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence</Hit_def>
  <Hit_accession>KM660696</Hit_accession>
  <Hit_len>1447</Hit_len>
  <Hit_hsps>
    <Hsp>
      <Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
      <Hsp_bit-score>874.117</Hsp_bit-score>
      <Hsp_score>968</Hsp_score>
      <Hsp_evalue>0</Hsp_evalue>
      <Hsp_query-from>1</Hsp_query-from>
      <Hsp_query-to>502</Hsp_query-to>
      <Hsp_hit-from>1447</Hsp_hit-from>
      <Hsp_hit-to>948</Hsp_hit-to>
      <Hsp_query-frame>1</Hsp_query-frame>
      <Hsp_hit-frame>-1</Hsp_hit-frame>
      <Hsp_identity>496</Hsp_identity>
      <Hsp_positive>496</Hsp_positive>
      <Hsp_gaps>2</Hsp_gaps>
      <Hsp_align-len>502</Hsp_align-len>
         <Hsp_qseq>AAAGGTTACCCCCACCGACTTTCGGGTGTTACAAACTCTTCGTGGTGTGACNGGGCGGTGTGTACAAGGCCCCGGGAAACGTANTTCANCCGCGGCATGCTGATCCGCGATTACTAGCGATTCCAGCTTCATGTAGGCGAGTTGCAGCCTACAATCCGAACTGAGAACGGTTTTATGAGATTAGCTCCACCTCGCGGTCTTGCAGCTCTTTGTACCGTCCATTGTAGCACGTGTGTAGCCCAGGTCATAAGGGGCATGATGATTTGACGTCATCCCCACCTTCCTCCGGTTTGTCACCGGCAGTCACCTTAGAGTGCCCAACTGAATGATGGCAACTAAGATCAAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCAACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAACCATGCACCACCTGTCACTCTGCTCCCGAAGGAGAAGCCCTATCTCTAGGGTTGTCAGAGGATGTCAAGACCTGGTAAGGTTCTTCGCGTTGCTTCGAATT</Hsp_qseq>
         <Hsp_hseq>AAAGGTTACCCCCACCGACTTTCGGGTGTTACAAACTCTTCGTGGTGTGACGGGCCGGTGTGTACAAGGCCCCGGGAA-CGTA-TTCACCCGCGGCATGCTGATCCGCGATTACTAGCGATTCCAGCTTCATGTAGGCGAGTTGCAGCCTACAATCCGAACTGAGAACGGTTTTATGAGATTAGCTCCACCTCGCGGTCTTGCAGCTCTTTGTACCGTCCATTGTAGCACGTGTGTAGCCCAGGTCATAAGGGGCATGATGATTTGACGTCATCCCCACCTTCCTCCGGTTTGTCACCGGCAGTCACCTTAGAGTGCCCAACTTAATGATGGCAACTAAGATCAAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCAACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAACCATGCACCACCTGTCACTCTGCTCCCGAAGGAGAAGCCCTATCTCTAGGGTTGTCAGAGGATGTCAAGACCTGGTAAGGTTCTTCGCGTTGCTTCGAATT</Hsp_hseq>
      <Hsp_midline>||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| || ||||||||||||||||||||||| |||| |||| |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||</Hsp_midline>
    </Hsp>
  </Hit_hsps>
</Hit>
</Iteration_hits>
  <Iteration_stat>
    <Statistics>
      <Statistics_db-num>41176984</Statistics_db-num>
      <Statistics_db-len>113854703</Statistics_db-len>
      <Statistics_hsp-len>0</Statistics_hsp-len>
      <Statistics_eff-space>0</Statistics_eff-space>
      <Statistics_kappa>0.41</Statistics_kappa>
      <Statistics_lambda>0.625</Statistics_lambda>
      <Statistics_entropy>0.78</Statistics_entropy>
    </Statistics>
  </Iteration_stat>
</Iteration>
</BlastOutput_iterations>
</BlastOutput>
```